# Someone know special sign in cloud zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zooming

in a cloud-zoom js file i found a strange symbol

```
$mouseTrap = jWin.parent().append(format("<div class='mousetrap' style='background-image:url(\".\");z-index:999;position:absolute;width:%0px;height:%1px;left:%2px;top:%3px;\'></div>", sImg.outerWidth(), sImg.outerHeight(), 0, 0)).find(':last');
```

someone can expain for me pls.And most specific is "width:%0px"?what is %0px mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like placeholder for templator.
Seems this placeholders  `%0, %1, %2, %3` will be replaced values  with values `sImg.outerWidth(), sImg.outerHeight(), 0, 0`.

Comment: Look at format() functon, which receive 5 arguments: html string and 4 values. This 4 arguments would be inserted in place of markers %0, %1, %2, %3. I think it works like String.Format() method in .net or String.format() in java.